# Compiler can't find a class for Class.forName()

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, annotations

Tried to compile the .java file from `Thinking in Java`.

```
package pck;
/...
public class AtUnitExample1 {
    public String methodOne() { return "This is methodOne"; }
    @Test boolean testMethodOne() { return methodOne().equals("This is methodOne"); }
    // ...
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // OSExecute.command("java net.mindview.atunit.AtUnit pck.AtUnitExample1"); // ORIGINAL
        OSExecute.command("java -classpath ./out/production/Exercises/ net.mindview.atunit.AtUnit pck.AtUnitExample1"); // My version
    }
}
```

Сlass `AtUnit` is a kind of realization of `JUnit` testing, it checks methods with `@Test` annotation using reflection. And it takes the name of the сlass for checking as an command-line argument.

But when I try to compile the original, the compiler throws an `OSExecuteException` that says `Could not find or load main class net.mindview.atunit.AtUnit`.

I thought that it could be a problem with different locations of classes and changed the command. In this case I have `FileNotFoundException` with the message: `/mnt/data-disk/MEGA/Программирование/Java/Exercises/pck.AtUnitExample1.class (No such file or directory)`. The exception appears when `AtUnit` try to call a `Class.forName()`.

What's wrong?

The structure of packages:

[image]

[image]

UPD: I renamed the folder with cyrillic symbols, but it doesn't help.

UPD2: The project classpath:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
/mnt/data-disk/MEGA/Programming/Java/Exercises/out/production/Exercises/
/home/nikita/Downloads/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
/opt/idea-IC-172.3317.76/lib/idea_rt.jar
```

Comment: I guess the first thing to do is see if it's on the classpath, you can do that following this https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/

Comment: Which classpath have you printed in UPD2? Since you're spawning a new java process, the classpath might be different from your main process.

Comment: I compiled the code J Smith sent me above

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution. I just have changed the command in `OSExecute.command()`, according to my case it must be `java -classpath ./out/production/Exercises/ net.mindview.atunit.AtUnit ./out/production/Exercises/pck/AtUnitExample1.class` in there.